# Formatting timestamp using date-fns-tz keeps returning 1970

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, date-fns, date-fns-tz

I have a timestamp which is being returned from Stripe which is `1695112577` ... If i punch it into https://www.epochconverter.com/ it returns the correct date `Tuesday, 19 September 2023` But if i try and use `date-fns-tz` to convert it, it keeps returning 1970 ... I am trying to return it in the users timezone;

```
import { formatInTimeZone } from 'date-fns-tz'

formatInTimeZone(new Date('1695112577'), user.timezone, 'eeee, MMMM do yyyy h:mm aaa')
```

Comment: You need to pass a **number** to `new Date()`, not a string, and that timestamp value should be multiplied by 1000.

Comment: `new Date(data.current_period_end / 1000)` seems to give back 1970 also

Comment: **multiplied** by 1000